# Fast/Optimized way to flip an RGBA image vertically

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a `byte[]` for a RGBA array. I have the following method that flips the image vertically:

```
    private byte[] FlipPixelsVertically(byte[] frameData, int height, int width)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[frameData.Length];

        int k = 0; 
        for (int j = height - 1; j >= 0 && k < height; j--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width * 4; i++)
            {
                data[k * width * 4 + i] = frameData[j * width * 4 + i];
            }
            k++;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

The reason I am creating `new byte[]` is because I do not want to alter the contents of `frameData`, since the original info will be used elsewhere. So for now, I just have a nested for loop that copies the byte to the proper place in `data`.

As `height` and `width` increase, this will become an expensive operation. How can I optimize this so that the copy/swap is faster?

Comment: first step is to use `Array1.CopyTo` instead of internal loop

Comment: @IłyaBursov: `Buffer.BlockCopy` would be quite a bit better.

Comment: Anytime you are copying bytes on a modern system, you are wasting up to 88% of your time.  If alignment and architecture allows, at least copy using CPU word sizes.

Comment: It is a built-in primitive that is heavily optimized, Image.RotateFlip().  But it might be worth focusing a bit on why you need this, could well be an oops elsewhere.  Bitmaps are quirky, they are stored upside-down in memory.  The last line of pixels is first.  Address that and you won't need this code.  Of course we can't help with that when the snippet only shows the thing you don't want to do.

Comment: @HansPassant If they are stored upside-down in memory, then it is true that the last line of pixels is first. But what do you mean by "address that and you won't need this code"? Because from my understanding, doesn't "last line of pixels is first" also apply to all lines, i.e. second last line is the second line. How can I flip without going through all the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
private byte[] FlipPixelsVertically(byte[] frameData, int height, int width)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[frameData.Length];

    int k = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
    {
        int j = height - k - 1;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(
            frameData, k * width * 4,
            data, j * width * 4,
            width*4);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: It should be `Buffer.BlockCopy(frameData, k * width * 4,data, j * width * 4,width*4)`. Nonetheless, thank you - it's much faster.

Comment: @JohnW Thanks for the correction. I updated the answer.